# Random and images of numbers aren't same iOS xCode

Tags: ios, objective-c

My problem is that I generate a number with **random from 0 to 9** to then appear the image with the number that it generate:

**Implementation:**

```
@implementation EscenaJuego{
    int numberSelected;
    int num;
    NSString *form;    
}
```

**AddImage Number:**

```
-(void)addNumber
{
    num = arc4random() % 10;
    form = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", num];
    SKSpriteNode *numero;
    numero = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:form];
    [numero setScale:0.5];
    ......
}
```

**When both bodies touch , do NSLog:**

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    SKPhysicsBody *primerCuerpo, *segundoCuerpo;
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
    {
        primerCuerpo = contact.bodyA;
        segundoCuerpo = contact.bodyB;
    }
    else
    {
        primerCuerpo = contact.bodyB;
        segundoCuerpo = contact.bodyA;
    }


    if ((primerCuerpo.categoryBitMask & categoriaPersonaje) != 0 &&
        (segundoCuerpo.categoryBitMask & categoriaMovimiento) != 0)
    {
        numberSelected = num;
        NSLog(@"%d", num);        
    }
```

But then when I do NSLog to get if the number is the same that the image , **is different**.

**Example**: When I my character touch 9, NSLog said that is 2.

[image]

All image files are their **number.png**

**Edit:**

If I do a NSLog in AddNumber method the number is correct with the image:

```
-(void)addNumber
{
    num = arc4random() % 10;
    form = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", num];
    SKSpriteNode *numero;
    numero = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:form];
    [numero setScale:0.5];
    self.numeroSeleccionado = [form integerValue];
    NSLog(@"%@%d", @"Appear:", self.numeroSeleccionado);
    ......
}
```

Comment: Code you post the code concerning your nslog?

Comment: Why are `num` and `form` instance variables?

Comment: You can see my edit question

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `num` is an instance variable, so it will hold the last value that was set into it. That's what you log. In your code you don't update the variable on contact detection before you use it.

Consider setting the `name` of the sprite nodes and using that when contact is detected to determine what actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass a `SKSpriteNode` and create a number property in it. This will simplify your code and make it more clear.

```
@interface NumberNode : SKSpriteNode
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger number;
@end
```

You will not have to have a `int num` then. You would just check the `number` property of the collided node.

Comment: I've done that but it does the same... in AddNumber method:    `self.number = [form integerValue];`

Comment: Show your updated code in the question. Delete the num and form instance variables.

Comment: And what should I do? with properties?

Comment: I deleted the instance variables (num and form) and I did with properties but it does the same